# Is there some sane way of getting "localized" (translated) PHP syntax aliases?

Tags: php, localization, translation

For many years, I coded in English, even wrote comments in English, in spite of English not being my native language, and in spite of me not distributing the code. A few years ago, I finally made the switch over to my native language, and somehow, it feels more "real", as if I'm not "pretending". It's difficult to describe the feeling, but it's real.

Anyway, even though I have made my own functions which wrap around the built-in PHP functions, defined various constant aliases, make my own functions and all comments in my native tongue, there are things which really bug me. All of the "language constructs"/syntax are still in English. For example:

```
function teste($kollektionen)
{
    foreach ($kollektionen as $a)
        // ...
}
```

I would like it to be (for example):

```
funktionen teste($kollektionen)
{
    jeden ($kollektionen zu $a)
        // ...
}
```

To the best of my knowledge, language constructs such as "function" or "foreach" (and many more) cannot be "aliased" easily.

The only "suggestion" I've been given in the past when asking about this is to "recompile PHP with your own changes". Let me just make it clear right away that this is completely out of the question. There must be no recompiling of PHP or any other "advanced hacking" like that. I wish PHP would just understand an "alias file" or something which I can just put somewhere and which simply contains lines such as:

```
'jeden' => 'foreach',
'funktionen' => 'function',
...
```

And then PHP would work as normal, but *also* treat any (non-quoted) instance of "jeden" as "foreach" and "funktionen" as "function", etc. Very simple. It would just translate them internally before doing its usual thing.

To me, this seems more than possible in theory. In fact, it probably would be trivial (for the people in charge, with the expertise) to implement. Sadly, however, it isn't trivial for *me* to add to PHP, so any solution which involves me modifying PHP is "dead on arrival", I'm afraid.

It already understands non-ANSI characters for variable names and whatnot, so that's not an obstacle.

It would be psychologically pleasant to be able to code fully in your native language, while still using PHP and not having to make some "language fork" just for this, which, again, is completely unrealistic and also counter-productive. Being forced to maintain my own branch of PHP just to get translated syntax keywords would be far more trouble than it would ever be worth, as I hope you can all understand.

To be clear: this is not some "different language"; I'm just talking about PHP with *aliases* for the syntax. The normal, English syntax would not be touched; it would just gain additional, translated syntax which is completely optional and not enabled by default. Perhaps it could be like:

```
<?php

    ini_set('syntax_aliases_file', 'mytranslations.ini');
    define('RADEBYTEN', PHP_EOL);

    funktionen test()
    {
        schreiben 'Hallo!' . RADEBYTEN;
    }
```

In the above example, the mytranslations.ini defines "funktionen" as an alias for "function" and "schreiben" as an alias for "echo".

Considering the numerous *actual* improvements PHP has received in later years, this doesn't sound at all "out there" to me. In fact, I'm not at all convinced that it doesn't already exist! Many functions which I found after using PHP for 15-20 years had been there all along and solves some problem which I had struggled with on my own because I just didn't know about the feature.

Comment: As code must be clear to any programmer using your native language is not an option.

Comment: @u_mulder What do you mean? Why must code be clear to "any programmer"?

Comment: _“In fact, it probably would be trivial (for the people in charge, with the expertise) to implement.“_ - in all likelihood, they have better things to do than waste their time on something like this.

Comment: As mentioned, this code is not for global distribution. Besides, the comments, function and variable names are still not in English anyway, so...

Comment: You can write your own extension that does these things. Thus all runtimes you want you execute your code need your extension. There is no built-in feature to support your idea.

Comment: "You can write your own extension" ... I thought I made clear that I can't. What's with the hostile replies?

Comment: Then you have to accept that there is no solution. What do you expect here?